# Create User and Group on Docker Alpine Linux with root privileges

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, alpine-linux

I have a Dockerfile on Ubuntu server where I create a user on group www-data with root privileges.

> RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u userid (like 1000) -d /home/user (like www) user

> RUN mkdir -p /home/user/.composer && 
> chown -R user:user /home/user

How I can do the same in alpine linux ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to "create a user with root privileges"; just set `USER root` if that's what you need.